# Is the rtctime module available in NodeMCU for ESP32

Tags: esp32, nodemcu

For ESP8266 there is a very useful implementation of NTP in the [rtctime](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/rtctime/) module.

I looked through the [documentation](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev-esp32/) as well as the `dev-esp32` branch in the [source code](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/tree/dev-esp32) and couldn't find it.

Is there a plan to port that module over to ESP32?

Answer (score 0):

Duh - there is a module called [time](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev-esp32/modules/time/) that gives the `NTP` functionality. I must be blind not seeing that before.